# A Positively definite matrix, then $c_1\|x\| \leqslant \|Ax\| \leqslant c_2\|x\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a symmetry, positively definite $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, I want to prove that there exists constant $0<c_1<c_2$ such that for any vector $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$
$$
c_1\|x\| \leqslant \|Ax\| \leqslant c_2\|x\|
$$
I just Remember some basic properties of positively definite matrix, so I try to prove it.
Suppose $\|x\|=1$. We know that there exists an orthogonal matrix $B$ ($BB^T=I$) such that $A=B^T CB$, where $C$ is a diagonal matrix with $a_{ii}=\lambda_i$. Then $A^TA=B^TC^2B$, note that $C^2$ is a diagonal matrix with $c_{ii}=\lambda^2_i$. It follows that
$$
\|Ax\|^2=x^TA^TAx=x^TB^TC^2Bx=(Bx)^TC^2Bx.
$$
Note that 
$$
\|Bx\|^2=x^TB^Tx=x^Tx=\|x\|^2=1,
$$
Suppose $Bx=(b_1,...,b_n)$, then we have $\|Ax\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 b_i^2$. Thus
$$
\min_i \lambda_i \|Ax\| \leqslant \max_i \lambda_i \|x\|
$$
Is my proof right? And can we relax the condition to be $A+cI$ is positively difinite for some positive constant $c$?

Comment: I think your proof is correct. Only in the end you should have written  $\min\limits_{i}{\lambda_i}\|x\|\leq \|Ax\|\leq \max\limits_{i}{\lambda_i}\|x\|$ and to note that all $\lambda_i>0$, because you take a square root of $\max\limits_{i}{\lambda_i^2}$ which is $\max\limits_{i}{|\lambda_i|}=\max\limits_{i}{\lambda_i}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The set $\|x\|=1$ is compact in $\mathbb R^n$ and the function $f(\vec x)=\|A\vec x\|$ is continuous on this set. Then $f$ achieves its maximum and minumim value over the set $\{\vec x\in\mathbb R^n:\|\vec x\|=1\}$. Denote the minimum by $c_1$ and the maximum by $c_2$. Then see what happens for arbitrary vector $\vec x$ (not necessarily unit) and use the fact that $A$ is s.p.d to show that $c_1>0$